# How to know when user stop editing autocomplete field in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have an input with an autocomplete of angular-ui-typeahead.

The user start typing, and they can choose an option from the autocomplete, or type the text that is not listed.

If the user does not use the autocomplete, I must change the text of a label, saying that `this element will be added`

```
<input
    ng-blur="checkIfNewProvider()" 
    ng-model="providerSelected" 
    uib-typeahead="provider as provider.name for provider in providers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" placeholder="{{ 'new-product.provider.placeholder' | locate }}" 
/>
```

I was checking on the blur of the field if the option choosed was or not on the autocomplete.

The problem is that, when the user click on the option menu that the autocompelte shows, the blur is triggered, and the label changed.

After leaving the field again, the blur is triggered again, and the label text is fixed.

What event can I trigger, or what can I do to fix this?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle with your problem? that would be very helpful.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vk1WT3IQKOX3FhtIxfHn?p=preview

Here is an example, please write on the input, and choose from the autocomplete with your mouse (NOT using enter)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the *directive*'s attribute `typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label)` which triggers your *function* when selecting an element fromt the *dropdown*:

```
    <input 
        type="text" 
        ng-blur="blur()" 
        typeahead-on-select="blur()" 
        ng-model="selected" 
        uib-typeahead="provider as provider.name for provider in providers | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

Another attempt, but not really suggested, would be to `$watch` the *model* and check if it matches an element from your *array*.

Comment: Yes, but on `typeahead-on-select` runs after `blur`, so the problem is the same. I cannot remove the blur, otherwise if the text write is not on the autocomplete, I cannot check

Comment: Yep, but it immediately rechanges due to `typeahead-on-select`. Did you try using a `$watcher`?

Comment: Right, but it looks bad. I dont know what is a watcher. I will look for it. If have an exaple please paste. Thanks

Comment: Using a `$watcher` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) would be like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/2H4XPXInYFzd7LGIZkXJ?p=preview